# Git workflow with LaTeX files and multiple commiters

Tags: git, latex

I've started writing a new article and I decided to use `git` to track the changes made to my main Latex file (and the bibliography `.bib` file) I have two advisors who will also be making changes to the Latex file. Neither of them knows how to use `git` and asking them to learn would be impossible. So I'm left with the following workflow:

- I make edits to the files and use git to track the changes.
- Advisor 1 makes some changes and sends the file via mail back to me.
- Advisor 2 makes some other changes and sends the file via mail back to me.

So at the end of the day I have three modified versions of the same LaTeX file that need their changes to be tracked and at some point to be merged into a single file.

I'm brand new to `git`. What workflow would you recommend?

Comment: You're brand new to git; your advisors don't know it at all either; yet you decided to use it?  Why?

Comment: Because I've learned the hard way that you need a system to track changes to avoid pointless by-hand change tracking and files merging. I also use `python` to write code so I figured I might as well bite the bullet and learn git.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question is mostly personal opinion bait, but here's mine anyway.

It would be a lot easier for you at least to get your advisors to learn git as well.  The inconvenient part of concurrent editing (no matter the SCM) is to manage and merge conflicting edits.  But if you keep your advisors out of it, all the hard work will be for you.

Failing that, you could track their changes on a branch each.

```
git branch advisorA advisorB
```

Then each time they send you their changes, you'd commit it to their branch and merge into yours:

```
git checkout advisorA
mv /external/advisorA/updated_file file_in_git
git commit -am'Revision from advisor A'

git checkout master
git merge advisorA
```

After the branches diverge too much, merging will grow more and more painful, and you will want to send your advisors a more up-to-date file.  When you do, be sure to track it by doing the reverse merge:

```
git checkout advisorB
git merge master

git checkout master # don't stay on your advisor's branch!
```

The general rule is: your advisors' branches always contain the latest state they have of the files.

The history line you'll get from that sort of workflow will tend to look messy, but this is the easiest git workflow to explain.  After you grow more comfortable with it, you might want to shift towards a rebase workflow, that yields better-looking histories, at the cost of enhanced opportunities to mess things up.